# How we can display the date in Dojo DateTextBox with different formate like MM*dd*yyyy?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to display date in dojo dateTextBox on basis of user preference like..

If user to to display the date in MM*dd*yyyy dojo dateTextBox shoulld display in this formate.

Separator can be changes as per user from '/' to '-' to '*' .

I have the code below:

define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dijit/form/DateTextBox', 'dojo/date/locale', 'cgi/ec/mvc/_UnsavedChangesListenerMixin', 'cgi/ec/mvc/_UnsavedChangesDisabledListenerMixin',
        'dojo/dom-class', "dojo/_base/config", 'dojox/mvc/at'], 
function(declare, DateTextBox, locale, _UnsavedChangesListenerMixin, _UnsavedChangesDisabledListenerMixin,
        domClass, config, at){
    var _DateTextBox = declare( "cgi.ec.form.DateTextBox", [DateTextBox, _UnsavedChangesListenerMixin, _UnsavedChangesDisabledListenerMixin], {
        checkForChanges: false,
        allowFutureDate: true,
        additionalClasses: null,

```
    constructor: function(params, srcNodeRef){
        declare.safeMixin(this, params, srcNodeRef);

        var oldValue = this.value;
        if ( oldValue && oldValue.atsignature == 'dojox.mvc.at') {
            this.value = _DateTextBox.at(oldValue.target, oldValue.targetProp);
        }
    },

    _setValueAttr: function(value, priorityChange, formattedValue){
        var strValue = null;
        if(value !== undefined){
            if(typeof value == "string"){
                strValue = value;
                value = locale.parse(value, _DateTextBox.cacsFormat);
            }
        }
        this.inherited(arguments, [value, priorityChange, formattedValue]);
    },

    serialize: function(dateObject, options){
        var serialDate = locale.format(dateObject, _DateTextBox.cacsFormat).toUpperCase(); 
        return serialDate; 
    },

    postCreate: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        var dateBox = this;

        if (!dateBox.allowFutureDate) {
            dateBox.constraints.max = config.cgiConfig.systemDate;              
        }
    },

    startup: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);  
        var dateBox = this;

        if (dateBox.checkForChanges) {
            domClass.add(dateBox.id, "checkForChangesOnSave");
        }

        if (dateBox.additionalClasses) {
            domClass.add(dateBox.id, dateBox.additionalClasses);
        }
    }
});
_DateTextBox.cacsFormat = {selector: 'date', datePattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy', locale: 'en-us'};
_DateTextBox.parse = function(dateStr){
    var date;
    if(typeof value == "string"){
        date = locale.parse(dateStr, _DateTextBox.cacsFormat);
    } else {
        date = dateStr;
    }
    return date;
}
_DateTextBox.at = function(context, prop){
    return at(context, prop).transform({
        parse: function(value){
            if( value ){
                var strValue = locale.format(value, _DateTextBox.cacsFormat).toUpperCase();
                return strValue;
            } else {
                return value;
            }    
        }
    });     
}   
return _DateTextBox;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

looks that a working example (e.g. on CodePen) is required to fully see what you are experiencing, but here’s a link that may be useful when you use dojo/date/locale along with dojox/mvc/at: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mvc/at.html#data-converter

Hope this helps.

Best,
Akira